# Custom module change `foreach` to chose what to display

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom

I have a custom module for batch order in my magento application. I have created another store view and the batch order form will need to have different products in each store.

Here is part of the code that's responsible for the tabs is my order form. The content of the tab can be set in the admin panel.

Updated:

```
// Gets the block data.
$groups = $this->getGroups();
$mySelectedGroups = array('2', '4'); // this is the group entity_id from database


<!-- tab navigation -->
                <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <?php
                    // Loops through the groups to get their name as nav heading.
                    // The first iteration will activate the tab for the first group.
                    $navI = 1;
                    foreach ($groups as $group) :
                        if (in_array($group, $mySelectedGroups))
                        if ($group->hasProducts()) { ?>
                            <li <?php if ($navI == 1) { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
                                <a href="#<?php echo $group->getId(); ?>"
                                   data-toggle="tab">
                                    <?php echo $group->getName(); ?>
                                    &nbsp;<i style="display: none;" class="text-danger error_glyph_<?php echo $group->getId(); ?> fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <?php $navI++;
                        } endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <!-- ./ tab navigation -->
```

It pulls all the groups of products created in the admin. Can you tell me a way of calling them here 1 by 1 instead of bulk action?

I will then be able to set them manually for each store view.

Update:

That's the `getData()` for `$groups`:
[image]

It doesn't look like a normal array...

[image]

That's what the original looks like.

[image]

Here is the back end setting for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want but if you want to set the groups manually, you have to put them in an array something like this:

```
$groups = array('group1', 'group2', ...);

foreach ($groups as $group) :
...
```

**EDIT:**

```
$groups = $this->getGroups(); // your groups
$mySelectedGroups = array('group1', 'group2', ...);

foreach($group as $group) {
    if (in_array($group, $mySelectedGroups)) {
    //...
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** you have an error in your code

```
<?php
$groups = $this->getGroups();
$mySelectedGroups = array('1403', '1404', '1405'); // this is the group entity_id from database
?>

<!-- tab navigation -->
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
    <?php 
    $navI = 1;
    foreach ($groups as $group) :
        if (in_array($group, $mySelectedGroups)):
            if ($group->hasProducts()): ?>
                <li <?php if ($navI == 1) { ?> class="active" <?php } ?> >
                    <a href="#<?php echo $group->getId(); ?>"
                       data-toggle="tab">
                        <?php echo $group->getName(); ?>
                        &nbsp;<i style="display: none;" class="text-danger error_glyph_<?php echo $group->getId(); ?> fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php $navI++; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, this is how my navigation is created. All I want, is to select what groups to include within my navigation tab. For now all of the groups created in the backend are being displayed.

Comment: I have this: `$groups = $this->getGroups();` so it pulls all the groups but I am not sure what it pulls... Is this ID?

Comment: look my update please

Comment: No navigation is being displayed now, is there anyway of finding out what groups names are being pulled in here `$groups = $this->getGroups();`? It would make it easier for me to find out what to put in the array.

Comment: you should put in `$mySelectedGroups` the real groups ! , try `var_dump($groups)` or `var_dump($groups->getData())`

Comment: See my updated question, here is the code I have now but it is not displaying any navigation now. Also, how do you use the `getData()`? Will that work: `<?php echo var_dump($groups->getData()) ?>`?

Comment: Look my Edit 2.

Comment: Updated the code now. Have a look at the content of the `$groups`... not sure how should I do it now...

Comment: look my update `$mySelectedGroups = array('1403', '1404', '1405');`

Comment: Still nothing being displayed :( Driving me crazy now!

Comment: Hymmm... just looking at it, there beginning of it `array(6) { [2]=> object(`, the number `[2]` is the entity ID. I have checked the next categories and they all match. Is there any way to use these?

Comment: I tired `$mySelectedGroups = array('[2]');` and `$mySelectedGroups = array([2]);` but it ain't working.

Comment: Or is there way of excluding menu? There is `<?php echo $group->getName(); ?>` and if the name of it is "something" then `display:none`?

Comment: it's not a good way to hide them, i  gave you the best practice in my code, you have to find the groups values and put them in `$groups = $this->getGroups(); // your groups
$mySelectedGroups`